# Flutter and Dart Extensions

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, installation

I am trying to install Visual Studio Code for my class and I have installed the Flutter and Dart extensions, yet when I click on "start debugging" for my first program nothing appears in the "select environment" bar as I'm told it should.

Comment: Run `flutter devices` and put the output here

Comment: PS C:\Users\Owner\Documents\CEN_4360\flutter_complete_guide> flutter devices
2 connected devices:

Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 90.0.4430.212
Edge (web)   • edge   • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 90.0.818.56
PS C:\Users\Owner\Documents\CEN_4360\flutter_complete_guide>